# What is the difference between \def and \newlength?

Tags: macros, lengths

I wrote the following LaTeX documents.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\mywidth}{85mm}
\setlength{\myheight}{112mm}

\newcommand{\setpagesize}[2]{%
  \special{papersize=#1,#2}%
}

\setpagesize{\mywidth}{\myheight}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
\end{document}
```

I got following error messages from `dvipdfmx`and failed.

```
$ latex abc.tex
$ dvipdfmx abc.dvi 
abc.dvi -> abc.pdf

** WARNING ** Reading special command failed: "papersize=\mywidth ,\myheight "
[1
** WARNING ** Reading special command failed: "papersize=\mywidth ,\myheight "
]
4327 bytes written
```

When I use `\def` in place of `\newlength` and `\setlength`, it worked.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\def\mywidth{85mm}
\def\myheight{112mm}

\newcommand{\setpagesize}[2]{%
  \special{papersize=#1,#2}%
}
% ...


$ latex abc.tex
$ dvipdfmx abc.dvi 
abc.dvi -> abc.pdf
[1]
4331 bytes written
```

Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce that with my version of `dvipdfmx`. Perhaps try changing `\setpagesize{\mywidth}{\myheight}` to `\setpagesize{\the\mywidth}{\the\myheight}`?

Comment: @Bruno: I didn't get an error too, but I didn't get a sensible pagesize either. `\the` is certainly needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My version of dvipdfmx is "dvipdfmx-20110311 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks".

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 53):

`\newlength` is a LaTeX macro which defines a new length *register*, which holds a length as number and can be used for calculations (e.g. using `\addtolength`). The `\def` macro is the primitive version of `\(re)newcommand` and simply defines the content as string.

In your case you want to place the length as *string* inside the `\special` which is written into the DVI file. However, if you use the length register like `\mywidth` directly it doesn't return its value as string but awaits some operation like an assignment. You need to write `\the\mywidth` to get the string representation of the length register. However, a macro defined using `\def` is simply expanded by `\special` and its string content is simply added to the DVI.

Answer (score 25):

`\mywidth` is a length register, not a value. In some places it can be used as if it were a value, but if e.g. you would use simply `\mywidth` in the middle of your text you would get an error. You get the value of a length register with `\the`. So try `\setpagesize{\the\mywidth}{\the\myheight}`