# in=down modifier breaks \draw command when coordinate is returned by macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

Another Minimal Non-Working Example...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{20pt}
\newcommand*\mypoint{\mylength,20pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0pt,0pt) to [in=down] (\mypoint);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything is fine without the `[in=down]` modifier. Assistance welcome! I need a fix that retains the general structure; this is a simplification of a real situation in which I have hundreds of these `to [in=down] (\mypoint)` line segments in my draw command, where `\mypoint` is a different macro in each case, and it's not feasible to create a new node for every call of the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stored the value of `20pt` as a `length`, you should access its value using `\the\mylength`. Redefining your macro as `\newcommand*\mypoint{\the\mylength,20pt}` will work.

See [What is the difference between \def and \newlength?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15736/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newlength/15738#15738) for more details on using `length` macros.

Comment: Thanks! Is it not a bit bizarre that this error only appeared when the `[in=down]` parameter was invoked, though?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the `curveto` handler which replaces the `lineto` handler if you use something like `in=down` or `bend right` handles its coordinates differently.