# Other than syntax what is the difference between \dimen0= and \setlength{}{}?

Tags: package-writing, lengths, dimensions

I have been browsing around for a while trying to find an answer to the above question, and I have found some similar questions along with there answers, so I already have a vague idea how to answer my own question. As a result I am really just looking for confirmation.

First some similar questions:

- [What is the difference between \def and \newlength?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15736/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newlength)
- [What are the differences between \newdimen, \newskip and \newlength?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/what-are-the-differences-between-newdimen-newskip-and-newlength)

My understanding at this point:

`\dimen0=value` is a tex primitive, which does roughly the same thing as the following combination of latex commands `\newlength{\name}\setlength{\name}{value}` where the numerical identifier `0` fulfils the purpose of the name chosen with `\newlength`.

So my first real question is whether that is more or less correct? I also have a follow up question: When if ever is it appropriate to use the more basic version of some command?

I have recently embarked upon my first LaTeX project that really goes beyond mere usage. In my past usage, the distinction between basic Tex and LaTex commands simply never came up. I am increasingly getting the feeling that I need to read an actual book to get any further than where I am now, so for a final follow up question, I would like to ask the more experienced amongst you out there, how I might go about going beyond a competent user understanding of TeX.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The primitive syntax for setting the value of a length register is

```
<register name> = <value>
```

where `<register name>` is a symbolic name or `\dimen` followed by a number (eight bit normally, fifteen bit when the package `etex` is loaded).

Internal registers only have a symbolic name (for instance, `\hsize`). Length registers allocated by LaTeX or the user have both, but it's better to stick to the symbolic name. When one says

```
\newdimen\foo
```

TeX performs some calculations and then issues an instruction such as

```
\dimendef\foo=42
```

(the number will be different), so that `\foo` and `\dimen42` will refer to the same register. But the user doesn't need and *shouldn't* use this number, because it may change depending on the packages loaded at startup.

To the contrary, registers numbered from 0 to 9 are *never* allocated, so `\dimen0` (and the others) can be used as a scratch register for temporary computations.

Why did I write `\newdimen` instead of `\newlength`? Because `\newlength` actually issues `\newskip` and not `\newdimen`. The length registers defined by `\newlength` are *always* rubber lengths.

This explains why using `\setlength` is very recommendable. Saying

```
\newlength{\foo}
```

and then

```
\foo=10pt 
Plus is a Latin word
```

will trigger a weird error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
<*> Plus i
          s a Latin word
```

because an assignment to a rubber length register always looks for the keywords `plus` and `minus`. With

```
\setlength{\foo}{10pt}%
Plus is a Latin word
```

this won't happen, because it is translated into

```
\foo=10pt\relax
```

The LaTeX kernel also uses `\dimen` registers (allocated with `\dimen`) and for setting them one can use `\setlength`. Expert (or cargo cult) programmers may decide to use the primitive syntax for saving space and macro expansions, but this is not recommended to novices. Stick to the recommended ways, you've time to learn how to safely break the rules.

Answer (score 15):

You don't have the LaTeX syntax correct: the LaTeX equivalent is `\setlength` not `\newlength` the latter does not take a value argument, it just declares the register.

In unextended LaTeX `\setlength\mylength{5pt}` expands almost immediately to `\mylength=5pt\relax` so there really is not much difference, however packages and classes should always use the `\setlength` interface so that when the `calc` package is loaded the user benefits from the infix expression parser loaded by that package.

so for example `\parbox` internally uses `\setlength\hsize{#1}` rather than just `\hsize=#1\relax` to set the width of the text in the box. Because of that, if a document has

```
\usepackage{calc}
```

then the user can go

```
\parbox{\textwidth - 2cm}{...}
```

to set a box 2cm less than textwidth. If the infix subtraction were used as

```
\hsize=\textwidth - 2cm\relax
```

then `\hsize` would be set to `\textwidth` and "- 2cm" would be typeset as text at the start of the box.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the `\setlength` `\newlength` mixup. What I really meant to compare was `\dimen0=value` and the combination `\newlength{\name}\setlength{\name}{\value}`. I have seen those two used for identical purposes. I guess my muddled brain simply turned two commands into one. Funny how brains work sometimes.