# What's meaning of parameters when I want to fill area with different color with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill the area with different color within one page, and I find this question [How to change the background color within a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236949/how-to-change-the-background-color-within-a-page).

After reading the answer of the above question, I think the format is this:

```
\fill[<the color I want to use>] ([xshift=<the offset in x dirction>,yshift=<the offset in y dirction>]<one vertex of diagnol of the rectangle>) rectangle ([xshift=<the offset in x dirction>,yshift=<the offset in y dirction>]<another vertex of the same diagnol of the rectangle>);
```

So I write the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\amount}{0.33\paperheight}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[green] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north east);
  \fill[yellow] ([yshift=-\amount]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-2\amount]current page.north east);
  \fill[red]([yshift=-2\amount]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-3\amount]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to fill the page with three colors. But I get the error 'Dimension too large.'

Comment: Just a guess: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15736 (`\newlength` instead of `\newcommand`).

Comment: as @Dr.ManuelKuehner, said. Otherwise `-2\amount` is `-20.33\paperheight` which is a bigger shift than intended. so `\newlength\amount\setlength\amount{0.33\paperheight}`

Comment: thx, I get the intended result.

Comment: Should I turn the comment/guess into a **short answer** so that the question can be closed?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I agree.

Comment: You could also replace `yshift=2\amount` by `yshift=2*\amount` (and the same for the other `yshift` options). Then it will work with `\newcommand` too.

Comment: @esdd Modify my answer if you want. But I would *guess* that using `\newlength` is semantically better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `\newlength` instead of `\newcommand` to define a length (`0.33\paperheight` in your case).
- See [What is the difference between \def and \newlength?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15736) for mor information.